# bootstrap image after control and dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align bootstrap textbox control and image align to `center`, I don't know which `css class` to use?

and also bootstrap dropdown also aligning wrong and when first I load it is showing cross after clicking it is showing correct arrow. But still aliging on top.

[image]

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Committee.Type, new { @class = "control-label"})
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Committee.Type, new {  @readonly = "readonly", @class = "input-xlarge" }) 
        <a class="btn-link" href="#" rel="popover" data-title="Activity Type" data-content="Did we do a good job?"  >           
           <img src="~/Content/glyphicons_195_circle_info.png"  class="img-rounded" alt="Activity Type" /></a>
    </div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
         @Html.DropDownList("Role",(SelectList)ViewBag.Roles , new { @class =input-xlarge" })
         <img src="~/Content/glyphicons_195_circle_info.png" class="img-circle" alt="Activity Role" title="Activity Role"/>
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
   </div>
```

JS

```
 $('#Role').combobox();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms - under Horizontal forms, I believe that you need to wrap each label and control in a `<div class="control-group">` and give your form a class of `<form class="form-horizontal">` to get the layout that you want

e.g.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Committee.Type, new { @class = "control-label"})
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Committee.Type, new {  @readonly = "readonly", @class = "input-xlarge" }) 
            <a class="btn-link" href="#" rel="popover" data-title="Activity Type" data-content="Did we do a good job?"  >           
               <img src="~/Content/glyphicons_195_circle_info.png"  class="img-rounded" alt="Activity Type" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See my update to your Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FZZsu/2/